# figure spanning _one and a half_ columns in two columns environment

Tags: floats, two-column

I would like to have a figure spanning one and a half columns in a two columns environmnent. I would like to have it aligned to the left side of the page and some text can then be written on the remaining half column on the right side of the page.

I try to illustrate what my page layout would look like below :

```
|    figure        | text |
| text col 1 | text col 2 |
| text col 1 | text col 2 |
| text col 1 | text col 2 |
| text col 1 | text col 2 |
| text col 1 | text col 2 |
| text col 1 | text col 2 |
```

I tried to do something like :

```
\begin{minipage}[c]{1.5\textwidth}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{myfig}
\end{figure}
\end{minipage}
```

but it ends up not showing my figure at all. How can I reach the expected result ?

Comment: if the text is part of the figure, just use a normal `figure*` environment with a graphic and some text. If you want the text to flow automatically from the main document content to the narrow region so the reading order is `text col 1// text // text col 2` with the text breaking automatically then that is very hard to do in tex.

Comment: the text is not part of the figure, I would effectively like the main text to wrap around it in the narrow region very much as you describe. Ah is that so hard ? mmmmh.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : could there be a way to have the figure's caption to be in that narrow region then ? Would that be something easier to do ?

Comment: hard is perhaps not really putting it strongly enough. TeX does not support that. You would have to do the page breaking by hand and adjust the parshape of the paragraph by hand and then any edit anywhere in the document you would have to adjust to make sure the narrow lines came on the correct text.

Comment: putting the caption there is trivial, just `\begin{figure*}\includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{...}\hfill\begin{minipage{.25\textwidth}\caption{....}\end{minipage}\enfd{figure*}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sorry to bother you, but you seem to be very well informed. Let's suppose my caption is too long to be comprised in that small region, can i get it to wrap around my figure starting on the right and continuing below it on the full width of the page ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : also, the solution you propose is very elegant but it seems that the caption does not want to start at the top of the page but rather at approximately half of my figure's height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want this you can have it but it requires a lot of manual work that should be left until the document is done as any edit to the document forces a change of the settings. Basically you need to see where the paragraph breaks and then specify how many long and short rows are needed in each affected paragraph.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\z{\stepcounter{enumi}One two three four five six. }
\def\zz{Red yellow green \z\z\z \Roman{enumi} blue black white. }
\def\zzz{\zz\z \zz\zz\z\z\zz}
\begin{document}

\z\z\z

\begin{figure}[t]
 \begin{minipage}{1.5\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}

\caption{ Zzzzz zzz zzzz z z z zzzzzzzzzz  zzz}
\end{minipage}\hspace*{-.5\linewidth}
\end{figure}

\zz

\def\full{0pt \linewidth }
\def\short{.55\linewidth .45\linewidth }

\parshape 5
\full\full\full\full\short
\zz

\parshape 17
\short\short\short\short\short\short\short\short
\short\short\short\short\short\short\short\short
\full
\zzz
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is something I would not like to do however. It is too complicated and not very much "latexy" as I would have to count some lines as you say. I guess wrapping a caption around a figure is as hard. Overall, I am surprised that latex doesn't handle this properly, it seems to me quite simple to write text around a defined box... But I don't really know how latex works beyond what I type in my editor.

Comment: @Mary the problem is that latex breaks paragraphs in to lines, then lines of text in to columns (adding floats at that point) then breaking columns in to pages.  So by the time you know that a column of text is a left column on some page it is too late to go back and change the line breaking.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the sidecap package. This would have similar effect  except the side text are figure captions.

```
\usepackage{sidecap, caption}

\begin{SCfigure*}[\sidecaptionrelwidth][h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{charts/graph.png}
    \caption{A really long caption with a bunch of random text - Eos ipsa dolor hic consequatur inventore dignissimos libero in iusto modi ab similique asperiores.
    Sed ratione voluptatem non enim consequatur est sequi deleniti At voluptatem molestiae ut exercitationem dolore.}
    \label{fig2}
\end{SCfigure*}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and add an image of the result.